# How to install xev if it is not present

Tags: debian, apt, x11, xmodmap

I'm teaching myself about `xmodmap` and some of the tutorials say that you can get the keycode of a key by using `xev`.

When I try to run the command, I get
`-bash: xev: command not found`

Running `apt-cache policy xev` yields `N: Unable to locate package xev`.

Google searching and checking the various stack exchange sites also do not have any articles about installing `xev` if it is missing.

What package is it apart of and how do I install it?

I am running i386 Debian 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the command `apt-cache search '\<xev\>'`, you find that it's in the `x11-utils` package.